# mv() while reading

Tags: exception, interrupt

on Linux ext3 filesystem, what happens if mv() is called on the same file (file descriptor) while reading the file? It is actually an exam question and I can only say something like:

1. CPU traps OS for interrupt handling
2. etc, etc.

I would appreciate if OS guys out there can help me out, please :D

Comment: Is this `mv()` supposed to be a standard library function or the shell command or what?

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: You probably mean `rename()` *(system cal)* or `mv` *(user command)*. In any case I don't think interrupt handling is something you should be concerned about. Finding out if the file system allow that operation to start with may be more important.

Comment: @Matti mv() is the std lib's function and it is a syscall in some program. @S.Lott mv()ed the file but read()ing still continued as if nothing happend (and output and everything is as expected) @Alex yeah, but i think i'll stick to @WhirlWind's answer :D I have Functional Programing exam tomorrow!!! :) and the day after is OS!!! thanks guys for helps, cheers!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Linux rename man page:](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename)

That explains most of the details of this.

```
If one or more processes have the file open when the last link is removed,
the link shall be removed before rename() returns, but the removal of the
file contents shall be postponed until all references to the file are closed.
```